# Service instance is not available for child component in angular2

Tags: angular

I have created some services which should be shared within whole application but for some reason child components are throwing error
`Error: DI Exception at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor]`
I have provided all the services inside boot file

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    JwtHelper,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS, authervice, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
    categoryService,
    Configuration
]);
```

can anyone suggest something? if you need more explanation or code let me know.

category component

```
import ...
import {categoryService}       from './categoryService';
@Component({
    selector: 'category-list',
    template: `...`,
    directives: [],
    styles: ['.error {color:red;}'],
    providers: []

})
export class categoryComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _categoryService: categoryService) { }
    ...
}
```

If i add categoryservice in providers above it works otherwise throws error

complete error

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for categoryService! ORIGINAL
>   STACKTRACE: Error: DI Exception
>       at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:23)
>       at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:39:16)
>       at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:75:16)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:776:19)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:804:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:767:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:576:21)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/linker/element_injector.js:23:48)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/linker/element_injector.js:23:48)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:801:24)
>   ERROR CONTEXT: [object Object] zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise
>   rejection: EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider
>   for categoryService! ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: Error: DI Exception
>       at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:23)
>       at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:39:16)
>       at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:75:16)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:776:19)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:804:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:767:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:576:21)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/linker/element_injector.js:23:48)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/linker/element_injector.js:23:48)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:801:24)
>   ERROR CONTEXT: [object Object] ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ;
>   Value: ViewWrappedException {_wrapperMessage: "Error in :0:0",
>   _originalException: NoProviderError, _originalStack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at
>   NoProviderError.BaseExc…ngular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:801:24)",
>   _context: DebugContext, _wrapperStack: "Error: Error in :0:0↵    at ViewWrappedException.W…localhost:58056/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:35)"}consoleError
>   @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426 zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught
>   (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider
>   for categoryService! ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: Error: DI Exception
>       at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:23)
>       at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:39:16)
>       at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:75:16)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:776:19)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:804:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:767:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:576:21)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/linker/element_injector.js:23:48)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/linker/element_injector.js:23:48)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:801:24)
>   ERROR CONTEXT: [object Object]
>       at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:17:23)
>       at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:39:16)
>       at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_exceptions.js:75:16)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:776:19)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:804:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:767:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:576:21)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/linker/element_injector.js:23:48)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/linker/element_injector.js:23:48)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:801:24)
>   ERROR CONTEXT: [object Object]
>       at resolvePromise (http://localhost:58056/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32)
>       at http://localhost:58056/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:574:18
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:58056/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
>       at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:58056/libs/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:36:41)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:58056/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:355:43)
>       at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:58056/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:58056/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:36)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:58056/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22)consoleError
>   @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426

Comment: Could you give more details about the class where the exception occurs? Thanks!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier hi i updated question check

Comment: its a route-outlet class i also have the service initiated in appcomponent's constructor   constructor(private _categoryService: categoryService) { }

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure that `categoryService` is correctly imported in the boot module? What do you have if you use `console.log(categoryService);` before bootstrapping the application?

Comment: hi, it logs function categoryservice(http) and so on ....

Comment: hi if i do the same in category page it stops in debugger at this line     private _heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:58056/api/categories';

Comment: Could you create a plunkr with a subset of your application so I'll be able to reproduire your problem. Thanks!

Comment: ok will take some time as i dont know how to use plunkr.. but what about teamvwr or something like that??

Comment: Can you show us the whole text of your error? Something like `No provider for ...`

Comment: @yurzui updated question

Comment: @noobProgrammer: here is a plunkr that you can fork and update with your content: https://plnkr.co/edit/oDKyqDbgwE1YAxCfTNzI?p=info

Comment: @ThierryTemplier is there any way to push to plunkr??  i mean i am using lots of things to create plunkr file after file

Comment: @ThierryTemplier anyways i am working here just check code if you find anything suspicious https://plnkr.co/edit/qgQYSRXd6wgIQmgk1Mcz?p=info

Comment: @ThierryTemplier how to check errors its showing loading...

Comment: you wont believe what was causing error its path name `from "./something"`  to `from "./someThing"`  is it documented anywhere case sensitivity??

Comment: Here is your plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/C9khAF44ixenT0zhOBC4?p=preview I note that DynamicComponentLoader is deprecated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SystemJs** is case sensitive (by design). If you use different path name in your project files like this:

***main.ts***

```
import { categoryService } from './categoryService';
```

***category-component.ts***

```
import { categoryService } from './categoryservice';
```

then System js will make double imports
[image]

This way angular2 will find other instance of service object in providers Map keys.

[image]

Despite the fact that key exists in Map object.

[image]

`has` method of Map will return `false`. That's why you're receiving an error.

See also more information about key equality within Map object at this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Key_equality

Answer (score 1):

I think you do something the right way to specify your providers when bootstrapping your application.

You probably don't import correctly your service in the boot module. You could check that `categoryService` isn't undefined here:

```
import { categoryService } from './something';

console.log(categoryService); // <-----

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  JwtHelper,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS, authervice, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
  categoryService,
  Configuration
]);
```