# Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, exception, dependency-injection

Thank you for the comments I have edited to provide the code.

There are two services one that works and the second TradeDataService does not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMwml.jpg).

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routing, routedComponents } from './app.routing';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, Location } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule  } from '@angular/http';
import { SampleDataService } from './services/sampleData.service';
import { TradeDataService } from './services/tradeData.service';
import './rxjs-operators';

// enableProdMode();

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent, routedComponents],
    providers: [SampleDataService, TradeDataService, Title, { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**tradeData.Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { TradeData } from '../models/tradeData';

@Injectable()
export class TradeDataService {

   // private url: string = 'api/items/';
    private url: string = 'api';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getAllTrades(): Observable<TradeData> {
        return this.http.get(this.url + 'tradeData')
            .map((resp: Response) => resp.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    // from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html
    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

**stocks.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TradeDataService } from './services/tradedata.service';
import { TradeData } from './models/tradeData';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-stock',
    templateUrl: '/partial/stocksComponent'
})

export class StocksComponent implements OnInit {
    tradeData: TradeData;
    errorMessage: string;


    constructor(private tradeDataService: TradeDataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.tradeDataService.getAllTrades()
            .subscribe((data: TradeData) => this.tradeData = data,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

I can post more files if anyone wants to see them.

**tradeData.ts**

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
export class TradeData {
    id: number;
    firm: string;
    market: string;
    contract: string;
    clientCode: string;
    amount: number;
    currency: string;
    userId: string;
    tradeDate: string;
    maturityDate: string;
    orderCount?: number;
    //orders?: Order[];
    ordersTotal?: number;
}
export class Order {
    product: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
    orderTotal ?: number;
}
```

The log file has this in it.
core.umd.js:3064 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error
Error: DI Error
    at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError ([URL Snipped here]zone.js:992:33)
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (URL Snipped here]core.umd.js:1239:20)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (URL Snipped here]core.umd.js:1365:20)
    at new NoProviderError (URL Snipped here]core.umd.js:1405:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (URL Snipped here]core.umd.js:2937:23)

Comment: We need the full code to help you. You don't get to decide what can be helpful !

Comment: are u using cdn links for imports?

Comment: Are you using SystemJS?

Comment: Possibly dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765525/service-instance-is-not-available-for-child-component-in-angular2/37768637#37768637

Comment: That was really helpful. I looked at yurzui's comment and found a case issue.

Comment: Thank you for all who helped. This can be closed. Unsure how to close it.