# Static Injection error when using HttpModule

Tags: typescript, angular2-http

The following is the fragments of code which I am using :

**addorders.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/Http';
import {Headers} from '@angular/Http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-addorders',
  templateUrl: './addorders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addorders.component.css']
})

export class AddordersComponent implements OnInit {

  response;
  constructor(private http:Http) { }


.
. 
.
.
.

 post()
 {
    var json = JSON.stringify({productname:"Panasonic", price:100000});
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-forms-urlencoded');
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/orders",json,{headers:header})
    .map(res=>res.json)
    .subscribe(data=>this.response=JSON.stringify(data))
 }



 select(c)
 {
    this.post();
 }




  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AddordersComponent } from './addorders/addorders.component';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'
import {Router,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

//import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AddordersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,HttpModule,FormsModule,RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get a blank page at the browser and a console log as

AppComponent.html:23 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
    at *NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
    at NgModuleRef*.get (core.js:12110)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12608)

Why do I get this error even after adding the required code at app.module.ts ?

Comment: can you try chaning '@angular/Http'; to '@angular/http'; in the component file?

Comment: I changed '@angular/http' to '@angular/Http' in the app.modules.ts and got to remove the error in the console.

Comment: The paths should all be in lower case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765525/service-instance-is-not-available-for-child-component-in-angular2/37768637#37768637

Comment: Also, why are you using the deprecated Http service instead of HttpClient? Why are you using an unexisting encoding? Why are you sending JSON in the body and claiming it's application/x-www-form**s**-urlencoded? Why are don't you **call** the json() method? If the goal is to send JSON, why don't you let angular set the header and stringify the body for you? My advice would be to take a big step back, and read the official angular http documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: try HttpClient instead

Comment: @JBNizet Does that documentation apply to angular 2 ?

Comment: No. HttpClient exists since Angular 4.3 (IIRC). Angular 2 is out of date. Upgrade.